# Alternative to 'System Explorer'

Tags: windows-xp, monitoring, task-manager

OS: WinXP

I am used to use System Explorer 1.5 to monitor my PC. It provides:

1. A CPU usage icon on task tray.
2. A performance graph including CPU/MEM/Swap/Pages faulted/IO reads writes, also shows the process name which uses the most resources. So it's easy to check what's going on with my PC when a certain process slowing down the whole system.
3. In processes list, typing partial process name can filter out and narrow down to find a certain process.

But for some reason, the System Explorer causes the Kaspersky keep scanning my PC and never stops until I close System Explorer.

Before I found how to resolve this issue, I want to look for an alternative to System Explorer.

I tried Sysinternals Process Explorer, but it doesn't meet 2 & 3. Also it uses 10M memory and 30M swap which is relative high to System Explorer 4M/8M.

Is there any good process monitor tool? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) is a good alternative.

> Process Hacker is a feature-packed
>   tool for manipulating processes and
>   services on your computer.
>
> Key features of Process Hacker:
>
> - A simple, customizable tree view with highlighting showing you the
>     processes running on your computer.
> - Detailed performance graphs.
> - A complete list of services and full control over them (start, stop,
>     pause, resume and delete).
> - A list of network connections.
> - Comprehensive information for all processes: full process performance
>     history, thread listing and stacks
>     with dbghelp symbols, token
>     information, module and mapped file
>     information, virtual memory map,
>     environment variables, handles, ...
> - Full control over all processes, even processes protected by rootkits
>     or security software. Its kernel-mode
>     driver has unique abilities which
>     allows it to terminate, suspend and
>     resume all processes and threads,
>     including software like IceSword,
>     avast! anti-virus, AVG Antivirus,
>     COMODO Internet Security, etc. (just
>     to name a few).
> - Find hidden processes and terminate them. Process Hacker detects processes
>     hidden by simple rootkits such as
>     Hacker Defender and FU.
> - Easy DLL injection and unloading - simply right-click a process and
>     select "Inject DLL" to inject and
>     right-click a module and select
>     "Unload" to unload!
> - Many more features...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**[Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)** is a good alternative.

You may want to watch 2 snapsnots below for an impression:

[image]

[image]

They (Process Explorer, and some other useful small apps) can be found on [Microsoft - Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: The questioner says: "I tried Sysinternals Process Explorer, but it doesn't meet 2 & 3. Also it uses 10M memory and 30M swap which is relative high to System Explorer 4M/8M."